# Ruby on Rails, from an index action linking to individual item error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a ruby on rails project currently, doing it without scaffolding or anything just by hand. I have an index controller that simply lists all existing items in the db with a link on each that redirects to a details view.

The error I am getting is when trying to link to the item I have this line of code:

```
<%= link_to "Show", person %>
```

this is the same line of code I see everywhere, even in other working apps, I know person is the right variable name but no idea why this is failing. The error I get at runtime is:

```
undefined method `person_path' for #<ActionView::Base:0x7fe4d07f6568>
```

any helpful hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your "routes.rb" file. Make sure you have a declaration similar to:
  map.resources :people

If you open terminal and run "rake routes", it will show you all routes that are currently recognized by your app.

Comment: ahhh, one of the frustrating things about rails, knowing what's going on behind closed doors, it should handle this behavior by default! ugh, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the route for Person is not configured properly. Is the app using REST-ful routing? Read more at: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html